# POST Request - Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: angularjs, cors, http-post

Upon creating an **HTTP POST** request, this error shows on my log:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://url.com/test/test. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

Some may say that I should include `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : *` header on server-side. 
However, consider the following scenarios:
- I don't have access on server-side
- Why is it when I created an **HTTP POST** request using a 3rd Party **HTTP Requester** (A Firefox plug-in specifically), the request is processed successfully but not my request from an AngularJS app.

Answer (score 0):

Not all API's are accessible by ajax unless they are either CORS or JSONP enabled.

External rest clients are not bound to CORS restrictions like browsers are.

If the API isn't CORS enabled or serves jsonp then you need to use a proxy either on your server or third party to access the data